# How to populate select element in zend 1.12 from db

Tags: database, zend-framework, populate

i'm creating a application in which i need to populate data in select element from a db table.
i need to populate user roles from db 
my form code is

```
 $this->pass2->addValidator('Identical', false, array('token' => 'pass1'));
    $this->addElement('select', 'userrole', array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'required' => true,
        'multiOptions' => 
    ));
```

what should i do with multi options ?,
is there any way to load data from db in element using controller ,please helpme 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is to pass the db-adapter (or a model that knows how to do the required db query) to the form as a constructor parameter.

Something like this:

```
class Application_Form_MyForm extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;

        // Don't forget to call the parent __construct. Ultimately
        // it is the parent __construct() that calls your init()
        // method that adds your elements 
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        // Create your form elements
        // $this->addElement('text', 'my_text_field'); // etc

        // Now your select field...
        $this->addElement('select', 'my_select', array(
            'multiOptions' => $this->buildMultiOptions(),
            'validators' => array(
                // blah, blah
            ),
        );
    }

    protected function buildMultiOptions()
    {
        $select = $this->db->select()
            ->from('my_table', array(
                'my_value_column', 
                'my_display_column'
            ))
            ->order(array(
                'my_display_column ASC',
            ));
        $results = $this->db->query($select)->fetchAll();
        $return = array();
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $return[$row['my_value_column']] = $row['my_display_column'];
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller action, when you instantiate your form, you grab the db-adapter and pass it in as a constructor parameter:

```
$db = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('db');
$form = new Application_Form_MyForm($db);

// Then process your form as usual
```

Answer (score 0):

on case with is necessary populate options outside form class.

```
$form->getElement( 'ele_name' )
        ->setConfig(new Zend_Config( array(
            'multiOptions' => array('option1','option2') )
        )));
```